# How to get the value from Mutator/setter using classes

Tags: java

Good Day! I am trying to get the value of num1 and num2 using (this. operator) but no matter what i do i just cant take the value of this two number and put it on to num3. Im currently new in java programming thats why i`m not familiar yet in the syntax.

My Code:

```
public class FinalProject 
{

    public  Double num1;
    public  Double num2;
    public  Double num3;

public FinalProject ()
{

    this.num1 = 0.0;

    this.num2 = 0.0;

    this.num3 = 0.0;

}

public void setNum1(Double num1) //setter1
 { 

    this.num1= num1;

  }

public void setNum2(Double num2) //setter2
 {

    this.num2= num2;

  }

public void setNum3(Double num3) //setter3
{

   value3 = this.value1 + this.value2;

    this.num3 = num3;

  }

--------------- // GETTER -----------------

public Double getNum1()
 {

    return this.num1; 

  }

public Double getNum2()
 {

    return this.num2;

  }

public Double getNum3()
 {

    return this.num3; 

  }

}
```

------------------- // MY MAIN CLASS -----------------

```
package finalproject;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinalProjectMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        FinalProject output1 = new FinalProject();//num1
        FinalProject output2 = new FinalProject();//num2
        FinalProject output3 = new FinalProject(); //num3

        System.out.print("Enter your 1st number: ");
        output1.setNum1(input.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Enter your 2nd number: ");
        output2.setNum2(input.nextDouble());


        System.out.print("The sum of two number is: " + output3.getNum3());




    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to think about how you want `setNum3` to behave. At its current state:

```
public void setNum3(Double num3) //setter3 {

    value3 = this.value1 + this.value2;

    this.num3 = num3;

}
```

It does not compile. It seems like you are trying to assign the parameter to `num3` while also adding up `num1` and `num2`.

In my opinion, you don't need a `setNum3` or a `num3` field. Just put the logic of adding `num1` and `num2` in the `getNum3` method:

```
public Double getNum3()
 {

    return this.num1 + this.num2; 

  }
```

Also, you should just create one instance of `FinalProject` in your main, like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

FinalProject output = new FinalProject();

System.out.print("Enter your 1st number: ");
output.setNum1(input.nextDouble());

System.out.print("Enter your 2nd number: ");
output.setNum2(input.nextDouble());


System.out.print("The sum of two number is: " + output.getNum3());
```

Comment: Thanks alot you are saving me the only problem now is how can i call the public Double Getnum3() to my main method? 

sorry i`m new in coding